# Layout breaks on zoom in with "cmd +" but not with zoom in with mousepad

Tags: css, layout, zooming, pinchzoom

My simple portfolio site breaks when I zoom in, when I zoom with the mousepad nothing happens, it only breaks when I zoom with "cmd +" Any idea? Here's the repo
Whats the technical difference between the two mentions types of in browser zoom?

https://github.com/ramfiorentino/animated-ads-portfolio/blob/main/animated-ads-portfolio-vite/src/App.jsx

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdgHB.png)

I tried:

- adding margins in each section
- disabling the zoom with
- disabling zoom with touch-action css property in the body
- reviewed measure units and im only using fixed units for some widths, I dont see how this could break the layout vertically

Comment: One presumably triggers the actual page zoom, whereas the other only increases font sizes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.